# getting java package names

Tags: java

I have a java program which searches for files in a directory and returns names matching Test______.java, but i would want to find the package name for each of these java files.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to open each file and parse out the `package com.foo.bar` statement, wherever you find it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not actually loading these files into your current JVM class loader?  If you are, you can use introspection.

If not, you'll need to open the files using a FileInputStream, then use a BufferedInputStreamReader to read the file line by line and search for the package statement.